# Connect each point in the plot with all adjacent points

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following simple code. 
I need to connect each point in the plot with all adjacent points in vertical or horizontal line.

```
n = 5;
nodes = Flatten[
   Table[{i (16 2.54)/n, j (16 2.54)/n}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}], 1];
dataPlot = ListPlot[nodes, PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Large];
nodelabels = 
  Table[Text[
    Style[i + (n + 1) j + 1, 14, Bold], {0.7 + i (16 2.54)/n, 
     0.7 + j (16 2.54)/n}], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
elementlabels = 
  Table[Text[
    Style[i + (n) j + 1, 14, 
     Bold], {(16 2.54)/(2 n) + i (16 2.54)/n, (16 2.54)/(2 n) + 
      j (16 2.54)/n}], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
Show[Graphics[{{Red, nodelabels}, {elementlabels}}], dataPlot, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600]
```

I have manually added some lines to show what I am looking for.
[image]

**note:** there is a way to do that using ListLinePlot but this method requires to overlay so many ListLinePlot. I would prefer to get solution using Vertex functions.

Comment: I don't get it. What should be the result in the end?

Comment: This? `dataPlot=ListPlot[nodes,PlotStyle->PointSize->Large,GridLines->Union/@Transpose@nodes]`

Comment: Or just `GridGraph`?

Comment: @mfvonh, thanks for the answer. the grid did not appear with show? can you look at this issue?

Comment: @mfvonh. ok I got it. the GridLines has to be placed in the Show function. Thanks

Comment: @Öskå, Will GridGraph work if the spaces between nodes is not similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 5;
g = GridGraph[{n + 1, n + 1}];
vc = SortBy[ PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ 
                                   VertexList@g, Last] # - # &@(16 2.54/n);
g1 = SetProperty[g, {VertexCoordinates -> vc, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
                    ImagePadding -> 10, VertexStyle -> Red, VertexSize -> Small}];
Show[g1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 9 n}, {-1, 9 n}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great. you may change the plot rang to PlotRange -> {{-1, 16 2.54 + 1}, {-1, 16 2.54 + 1}} for cases when n is larger than 5. can this answer work for grid with not equal spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by " for grid with not equal spaces"?

Comment: @Algohi You can modify the `VertexCoordinates` so.., yes?

Comment: @Belisarius I mean not square grids. if the distance between nodes 1 and 2 vertical grids is not the same as that between nodes 2 and 3 or 3 and 4. some thing like this.

Comment: @Algohi Easy. Just adjust the `vc` calculation

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[ggF];
ggF[n_, m_, sc1_, sc2_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
       GridGraph[{n + 1, m + 1}, VertexCoordinates -> (Join @@ 
                 Array[{sc1, sc2} {#2, #1} &, {m + 1, n + 1}, 0]), opts]; 
      (* ignore the red syntax highligting *)

options = {VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexStyle -> Red, 
         VertexSize -> Small, Axes -> True, ImagePadding -> 20, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}};

ggF[5, 5, 16 2.54/5, 16 2.54/5, ImageSize -> 400, options]
```

[image]

```
ggF[5, 3, 16 2.54/5, 16 2.54/3, ImageSize -> 400, options]
```

[image]

```
ggF[5, 3, 16 2.54/5, 16 2.54/5, ImageSize -> 400, options]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to preserve the `Graphics` form, note that the `Table` used to generate `nodes` returns the vertical lines of those you seek.  Transpose to get the horizontal lines.

For example:

```
vertlines  = Table[{i (16 2.54)/n, j (16 2.54)/n}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
lines      = Flatten[{vertlines, Transpose@vertlines}, 1];
nodes      = Flatten[vertlines, 1];
(* other defs. as is *)

Show[Graphics[{Line[lines], {Red, nodelabels}, {elementlabels}}], dataPlot,
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or if you're concerned about efficiency and wish to omit the interior points of the lines, then use

```
lines = Flatten[{vertlines, Transpose@vertlines}[[All, All, {1, -1}]], 1];
```